# Mysterious multicast packets after bridging a bond0

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, network-bonding

I've got 2 interfaces eth0 and eth1 in a bonding (mode 4). Now I want working with kvm and let the instances communicate over a bridge br0.
Now my config changes. From this...:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 172.16.1.4
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 172.16.0.0
    gateway 172.16.1.1
    broadcast 172.16.255.255
    dns-nameservers 172.16.1.2 172.16.1.3
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 1
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1
```

to that:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-mode   802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 1
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 172.16.1.4
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 172.16.0.0
    gateway 172.16.1.1
    broadcast 172.16.255.255
    dns-nameservers 172.16.1.2 172.16.1.3
    bridge-ports  bond0
    bridge-fd     9
    bridge-hello  2
    bridge-maxage 12
    bridge-stp    on
```

Everything works fine except these notification from the firewall:

```
Source        Destination         Priority        Category        Note        Message
              224.0.0.22          info            ipmac-binding   DROP PACKET Drop packet ge2-0.0.0.0-C8:CC:6F:8E:D7:2F
```

All interfaces have the same MAC:

```
ifconfig | grep HWaddr
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:cc:6f:8e:d7:2f
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:cc:6f:8e:d7:2f
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:cc:6f:8e:d7:2f
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:cc:6f:8e:d7:2f
```

In a tcpdump I don't see any suspicious packages, arp table and routing table are looking fine...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some device on your network is [sending out IGMP queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address). Nothing to worry about.